# Django - How do I save the selected role?

Tags: python, django

I’m using [django-groups-manager.](https://github.com/vittoriozamboni/django-groups-manager)

I want to select the role of the member in the member addition form. I list the roles, but I do not know how to save the selected role. How can I do it? I'm waiting for your help.

[Screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/3zq9kT8/roles.jpg)

**forms.py**

```
class CalisanForm(UserCreationForm):
username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Kullanıcı Adı')
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')
password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Parola', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Parola Doğrulama', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(), widget=forms.widgets.RadioSelect(), empty_label=None)
roles = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=GroupMemberRole.objects.all(), widget=forms.widgets.RadioSelect(), empty_label=None)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = kwargs.pop("group_qs")
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["group"].queryset = qs

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'password1',
        'password2',
        'group',
        'roles',
    ]

def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Parolalar eşleşmiyor!")
    return password2

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    lenghtw = len(User.objects.filter(email=email))
    if lenghtw > 0 :
        raise forms.ValidationError('Bu email adresine sahip bir kullanıcı zaten var.')
    return email
```

**views.py**

```
def calisan(request):
queryset = request.user.groups
form = CalisanForm(request.POST or None, group_qs=queryset)
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save()
    group = form.cleaned_data['group']
    user.groups.add(AGroup.objects.get(name=group))
    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
    member = Member.objects.create(first_name=username)
    group = Group.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data['group'])
    group.add_member(member)
    user.save()
    password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
    return redirect('home')
return render(request, 'accounts/calisan/calisan.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Üye Ol'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
group.add_member(member, [form.cleaned_data.get('roles')])
```

Parameters that `add_member` accept:

- `member`: member (required)
- `roles`: list of roles. Each role could be a role id, a role label or codename,
  a role instance (optional, default: `[]`)
- `expiration_date`: A timestamp specifying when the membership
  expires. Note that this doesn't automatically remove the member
  from the group but is only an indicator to an external application
  to check if the membership still is valid
  (optional, default: `None`)